# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I want to pass data between this two page. Can load from new to new details page ald, but got problem here is what cannot get api data from detail page.

**news.html** new page

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="danger" no-border-bottom>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="ios-contact"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <ion-title>民安</ion-title>

  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

      <ion-item-group *ngFor="let new of news">

          <ion-thumbnail *ngIf="new.Preview_image1" item-start>
            <img src="{{new.Preview_image1}}">
          </ion-thumbnail>
          <button ion-item (click)="goToNewsDetail(new)">
            <h2>{{new.title}}</h2>
            <h2>{{new.publish_time}}</h2>
        <p>
            <ion-icon name="chatboxes">{{new.comments_count}}</ion-icon>
        </p>
        </button>


      </ion-item-group>

</ion-content>
```

**news.ts** new function page

```
import { Component, } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { NewsDataProvider } from '../../providers/news-data/news-data';
import { NewsDetailPage } from '../news-detail/news-detail';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-news',
  templateUrl: 'news.html',
})
export class NewsPage {
    news:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public newsData:NewsDataProvider){
    this.getNews();
  }

  getNews() {
      this.newsData.getNews().then(data => {
        this.news = data;
      });
  }

  goToNewsDetail() {
    this.navCtrl.push(NewsDetailPage);
  }

}
```

**news-detail.ts** . news details function page

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NewsDataProvider } from '../../providers/news-data/news-data';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-news-detail',
  templateUrl: 'news-detail.html',
})
export class NewsDetailPage {
    new: any;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public newsData:NewsDataProvider) {
        this.new = navParams.get('new');
  }

}
```

**news-detail.html** news detail page

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="danger">
    <ion-title>{{new.title}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
    news content
</ion-content>
```

**news.data.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class NewsDataProvider {
    data:any;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    //console.log('Hello NewsDataProvider Provider');
  }

  getNews() {

    if (this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('http://servertrj.com/api/news?api_key=123').map(res => res.json().data).subscribe(data => {
          this.data = data;
          resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you share your `NewsDataProvider`? You've included a lot of code that doesn't seem to be related to the issue (i.e. your views).

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen I upload NewsDataProvider code here ald. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are sending through your object `<button ion-item (click)="goToNewsDetail(new)">` but your method is not accepting it or sending it to the new page.

```
goToNewsDetail(newsItem:any) {
  this.navCtrl.push(NewsDetailPage, { new: newsItem });
}
```

You will now be able to accept it in the `NewsDetailPage` like you already have `this.new = navParams.get('new');`

You may also need to add a safe operator to the page as mentioned before `{{new?.Title}}`

On an unrelated note, you may want to change your `(click)` to a `(tap)`. the `(click)` event adds a 300ms delay to clicking to allow for double clicks, where the `(tap)` event acts like a normal mobile tap. This will also eliminate any unwanted accidental taps when your app is on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

Use safe operator

Change `{{new.title}}` to `{{new?.title}}`

**OR**

Declare `new` as `object`

Change `new: any;` to `new: any = {};`

**AND**

You also need to pass navigation parameter (`new`) to target page while pushing new page.

Comment: This only hides the symptoms, it doesn't necessarily fix the underlying issue.

Comment: I try ald, but still not working for me

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen, my bad i missed navCtrl.

Comment: @YuyangHe, you also need to pass valid navigation parameter to target page

Answer (score 0):

send 'new' parameter with push. write your 'goToNewsDetail' method like bellow.

```
goToNewsDetail(news) {

 this.navCtrl.push(NewsDetailPage,{new:news});

}
```

Comment: Show error in 'news' there
error: connot find name news. Did u means the instance member 'this.news'?

Comment: did you added 'news' in 'goToNewsDetail'?

Comment: When I add 'news' in 'gotoNewsDetail' show error again
error: parameter 'news'  implicity has an 'any' type.